# Beginner electricity and magnetism problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: problem]

The answer is: "Excess electrons will flow onto the ball's left edge only, causing a repulsive force to push the ball to the right."

Does the "ball's left edge" refer to only the tiny part where the rod makes physical contact with the ball or is it larger than that?
This is my second year of learning science, so I don't know much, but I thought that charged objects attract uncharged objects.
Also, could you please direct me to some online resources (websites, videos, etc.) that could teach me what I need to know to be able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the sequence is that induced charges are formed on the net uncharged ball and there is attraction between the rod and the ball.
The ball and rod touch and there is a transfer of negative charge to the ball in the region where the rod touched the ball.
The ball now has a net negative charge and is then repelled by the rod.

[Here is a demonstration with a metal coated ball which show the effect better.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57s7e9Dl2wQ)